# How to do a "for" loop with asynchronous condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, synchronous

I have this function:

```
waitForFreeAccnt.prototype.isMemberFree = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.api.getMemberInfo(function () {
        var accType = self.api.connect.accountType;
        console.log(accType);
        if (accType === 'FREE') {
            console.log('it is free');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('it is not free');
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

I would like to wait till the account is free for up to 10 seconds with something like that:

```
var test = function () {
    for (var start = 1; start < 10; start++) {
        var result = self.isMemberFree();
        console.log(result);
        if (result) {
            break;
        } else {
            self.api.pause(1000);
            console.log('waiting');
        }
    }
};
```

But it doesn't work because `self.api.getMemberInfo` is asynch call. This is super frustrating with Javascript. Any other language it would be so simple to do. How do I force the for loop to wait for `self.isMemberFree()` to finish executing before proceeding with the loop?

Also to note, this is not in browser execution so I don't care about anything hanging.

Comment: Does `self.api.connect` return some kind of deferred object or promise? You should wait for the object to be resolved before moving on to th next item.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I want it to make call 10 times and wait 1 second between calls. I don't care how long the call takes place. Let's say it taks one minute each call. So it could wait till 10 min and 10 seconds and I'll be fine.

Comment: @Terry, my bad, actually getMemberInfo returns some kind of object.

Comment: So after ten calls you want to continue even if the account is *not* free yet? Use `.setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` and put your next block of code in a function that you can call from within the `getMemberInfo()` callback.

Comment: Can't you use a setInterval instead?

Comment: @nnnnnn, correct, I want to continue regardless of the result. How do you mean?

Comment: @Terry, I am open to any suggestions. How do you mean? Please give a code snippet.

Comment: Try using promises and promise.all.

Comment: Why hasn't any bothered to bring up async/await..?

Comment: @towerofnix, i am curious to see your solution. please share your version!

Comment: @towerofnix Because the question is tagged ES6 and async/await are not part of the language standard yet.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue that makes sense, though OP asked so I answered :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have my work laptop today because it is Sunday, I'm coding this on sublime. Apologise if the syntax is a bit off.

To solve your problem I would recommend changing isMemberFree() to take in a callback function. This is because isMemberFree is async, and you will need a way to report the result after it has done the work.

Then change test function to use setTimeout API to wait a second. 
Wrap the function call for isMemberFree() to be in a nested function and call it recursively, that way you'll have synchronize control over the async calls.

Look at the coding example:

```
waitForFreeAccnt.prototype.isMemberFree = function (done) {
    var self = this;

    self.api.getMemberInfo(function () {
        var accType = self.api.connect.accountType;
        console.log(accType);
        if (accType === 'FREE') {
            console.log('it is free');
            return done(null, true);
        } else {
            console.log('it is not free');
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
};


var test = function () {

    var testMembership = function(waitAttempt, isFree) {
        if (isFree) { 
            return; 
        }
        else if (waitAttempt > 10) {
            // wait exceeded, do something.
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.isMemberFree(function(err, isFree) {
                testMembership(waitAttempt+=1, isFree);
            });
        }, /*total milliseconds in 1sec=*/1000);
    }

    testMembership(/*WaitAttempts=*/0, /*isFree=*/false);
};
```

What the above code does is that, presumably something has already been done to the member's account and now test function is called. So it waits for 1 second, then call isMemberFree function, this happens recursively until either isMemberFree() returns true OR the 10 seconds wait has been exceeded.

Comment: The non-free case should probably call `done(null, false)`.

Comment: @SamuelToh,  thanks for the help, but it gives `SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`. To simplify it, could you put these two functions into one. I mean, one would contain both functions.

Comment: replace break with return and give it a try.

Comment: You can skip the `=` in `waitAttempt+=1`

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with asynchronous code, you need to make use of callbacks. That is, if you want to do `a()` and `b()` in order but `a()` does something asynchronously, then you need to call `b()` from within `a()` once `a()` has a result. So **not:**

```
a();  // does something asynchronously
b();  // tries to use a()'s result but it isn't available yet
```

... but rather

```
a(b); // pass b to a() and a() will call it when ready

function a(callback) {
  triggerAsyncFunction(function(result) {
    if (result === something)
      callback("a just finished");
  });
}
```

Note that `a()` doesn't refer to `b()` by name, it just calls whatever function is passed in as an argument.

So applying that to your code, maybe something like this:

```
waitForFreeAccnt.prototype.isMemberFree = function (cbf) {
    var self = this;
    self.api.getMemberInfo(function () {
        cbf(self.api.connect.accountType === 'FREE');
    });
};
waitForFreeAccnt.prototype.testMemberXTimes = function(maxAttempts, callback) {
  var attempts = 0;
  var self = this;
  (function attempt() {
    self.isMemberFree(function(free) {
      if (free)
        callback(true);
      else if (++attempts < maxAttempts)
        setTimeout(attempt, 1000);
      else
        callback(false);
    });
  )();
};
this.testMemberXTimes(10, function(isFree) {
  // the next part of your code here, or called from here
  // because at this point we know we've tested up to
  // ten times and isFree tells us the result
});
```

Note that the way I coded `getMemberInfo()` it is basically doing the same thing yours was, but instead of returning a boolean it is calling the callback function and passing the same boolean value that you were returning. (I've removed the `console.log()`s to make the code shorter.)

Note also that you could structure the above to use promises, but the end result will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and your help! Appreciate it. However, I'll give it to Samuel Toh as his answer was earlier and I implemented it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You could return a Promise

```
waitForFreeAccnt.prototype.isMemberFree = function () {
  return new Promise((reject, resolve)=>
    // set a timeout if api call takes too long
    var timeout = setTimeout(()=> reject(Error('API timeout')), 10000);
    // make api call
    this.api.getMemberInfo(()=> {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      resolve(this.api.connect.accountType === 'FREE');
    });
  );
};
```

Then use it like this

```
whatever.isMemberFree().then(isFree=> {
  if (isFree)
    console.log('it is free');
  else
    console.log('it is not free');
})
// handle timeout or other errors
.catch(err=> {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on [naomik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905265/4633828), if you do it that way you can pretty easily use a `for` loop with it, using the (most likely) upcoming [`async`/`await`](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html) feature - though it's not part of ES2015.

```
// Note "async" here! That will make "await" work. It makes the function
// return a promise, which you'll be able to either "await" or
// "test().then" later.
var test = async function () {
    for (var start = 1; start < 10; start++) {
        // Right here we're using "await" - it makes JavaScript *wait* for
        // the promise that comes from self.isMemberFree() to be finished.
        // It's really handy because you can use it in loops like "for" and
        // "while" without changing the flow of your program!
        var result = await self.isMemberFree();
        console.log(result);
        if (result) {
            break;
        } else {
            self.api.pause(1000);
            console.log('waiting');
        }
    }
};
```

For now you'll need to use a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) or [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) before you can really use async/await, though. It's [only supported](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/) in Microsoft Edge 14 right now.

And a big emphasis that what is returned from `test()` isn't whatever you directly return from inside it. If I do this:

```
var test = async function() { return 15; };
var result = test();
```

I'm not going to get 15 - I'll get a promise that will resolve as 15:

```
result.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res); // 15
});

// or, use an async function again:
var main = async function() {
  console.log(await res); // 15
};
main();
```